# python/pygame image cant be found the the same folder

Tags: python, pygame

hello im new to python/pygame and tried to make a basic project. it did not turn out as planned as i don't understand this error if you can tell my why my image is not loading it will very much appreciated.  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\template\templat.py", line 15, in <module>
    screen.fill(background_colour)
NameError: name 'background_colour' is not defined`

this is the error i was speaking of however i have fixed now. how ever now the screen opens displayes the background and crashes.

```
   import pygame, sys

pygame.init()


def game():

 background_colour = (255,255,255)
(width, height) = (800, 600)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))


pygame.display.set_caption('Tutorial 1')
pygame.display.set_icon(pygame.image.load('baller.jpg'))
background=pygame.image.load('path.png')

target = pygame.image.load('Player.png')
targetpos =target.get_rect()


screen.blit(target,targetpos)
screen.blit(background,(0,0))
pygame.display.update()

while True:
  screen.blit(background,(0,0))
  screen.blit(target,targetpos)


running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False

      if__name__==('__main__')
  game()
```

Comment: How are you attempting to run this?  It looks like it should work to me.  Maybe the names of the files are wrong?  Wrong case perhaps?  Can you post the error?

Comment: i reworked some code and removed the error but now im getting something different. im not longer getting that error but now the screen opens displays the background and just closes.

Comment: p.s i also made changes and continued: this was the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nicolas\Desktop\template\templat.py", line 15, in <module>
    screen.fill(background_colour)
NameError: name 'background_colour' is not defined   :::       i noticed background color and removed and and that fixed the error but now the screen displayes for a second or two then crashes

Comment: Please format the code correctly, it's confusing to see where your error is! Try just copy/pasting the code and enclosing it in `<code>` tags...

Comment: @jadkik94: Please, instead of using `<code>` tags, indent code by four spaces (this is what the `{}` toolbar button in the post editor does for you).

Comment: @Greg Of course. But it seems he is having troubles doing that...

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `__init__` definition!

While your code does run, it is not what you want. There's an infinite loop inside the definition of the class, which means, however you are running this, there's something missing. You should put this code (most of it at least) inside the `__init__` function, and then create an instance of the class.

This is what I assume you want:

```
import pygame, sys

class game():
    width, height = 600,400

    def __init__(self):

        ball_filename = "Ball.png"
        path_filename = "path.png"

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        pygame.display.set_caption('Star catcher')
        self.background = pygame.image.load(path_filename)
        self.screen.blit(self.background,(0,0))

        self.target = pygame.image.load(ball_filename)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.screen.blit(self.background, (0,0))
            targetpos = self.target.get_rect()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # To run this
    pygame.init()

    g = game()

    g.run()
```

**UPDATE**:

I made more modifications than what you **must** do, but they could be useful. I did not test this, but it should be fine.

The error of width and height not being defined is because they are not local/global variables, but bound to the class and/or the instance of the class, therefore in their namespace. So you need to access these either via `game.width` (per class) or `self.width` (per instance, **only inside a method defined in the class**) or `g.width` (per instance, **if you are outside the class definition** and g is an instance of game class).

I hope I'm clear. :)

Comment: okay i ran the code you gave my but now its giving me a new error saying width is now defined and somthing about the __init__

Comment: i will be right back i have a errend to run if you can solve this while im gone i will thank you

Comment: The code I gave was just to give you an idea of what was wrong. I'll update my answer so that it should run.

Comment: I thank you for your help! but it seems to still be having a issue loading the ball.png that is in the folder. I looked over your code and have little understanding i'm thinking i need allot of reading and less development but then again you don't learn if you don't try!

Comment: The issue of finding `"Ball.png"` might be because in your original code you had `"baller.jpg"`, and `"Ball.png"` is just copied from jadkik94's version. Is the file you are trying to load a .png or a .jpg? and is it called "Ball" or "baller"?

Comment: @hammythepig I took the filenames from his previous post... I don't know what it is, but (to OP) be aware that filenames are case-sensitive on Linux/Unix (but not on Windows).

Comment: @Who885 Did you try with another image? (smaller may be better to test) Maybe the issue is with image size? I'm clueless without more details, traceback or anything